Angular 18 drag drop part of the data
In this component.html:
<div cdkDropListGroup>
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="meals" class="makeMeal" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let meal of meals" class="meal-drop">
    <img src="page_delete.png" (click)="deleteFood()" title="delete" />
    <h4>{{meal.name}}</h4>
    <label id="lblID" class="hidden">{{meal.id}}</label>
  </div>
  Add a meal:
  <input id="mealName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="mealName" name="mealName" required style="margin-left:10px;" />
  <img src="page_white_add.png" (click)="addMeal()" />
</div>

<p>My foods:</p>
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="foods" class="food-grid" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let food of foods" class="food-item">
    <img src="page_delete.png" (click)="deleteFood()" title="delete" />
    <h4>{{ food.name }}</h4>
    <ul>
      --> bunch of data <--

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  
I want to drag the food item and just add the name of the item and it's ID to the Meal item
I've tried this, but it doesn't work because I can't get past the data mismatch:
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Foods[] | Meals[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  } else {
    if (event.previousContainer.id === 'cdk-drop-list-foods') {
      const foodItem = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
      const mealIndex = event.container.data.findIndex(meal => meal.id === event.container.id);
      if (mealIndex !== -1) {
        this.meals[mealIndex].foods.push(foodItem);
      }
    } else {
      const mealIndex = this.meals.findIndex(meal => meal.id === event.previousContainer.id);
      const foodItem = this.meals[mealIndex].foods[event.previousIndex];
      this.meals[mealIndex].foods.splice(event.previousIndex, 1);
      // Add food back to foods array
      this.foods.push(foodItem);
    }
  }
}

export interface Foods {
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  protein: number
  carbs: number,
  potassium: number,
  id: number
}
export interface Meals {
  name: string,
  id: string,
  foods: Foods[]
}

I really just want to move the Name and ID from Food.

This was sufficiently hard to look up and to do that I wanted to post an answer. Here's what we're doing:
You have a collection of foods, and you have a collection of meals with foods in them.  You want to add foods to the meals:
export interface Foods {
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  protein: number
  carbs: number,
  potassium: number,
  id: string,
  isActive: boolean
}
export interface Meals {
  name: string,
  id: string,
  calCount: number,
  foods: Foods[]
}

The key to this is to add the food collection to the meal collection at the beginning.  You're then going to set up arrays in your HTML component to accept the data. This is what's going to let you merge one type of data into another.
private draggedFoodItem: Foods | null = null;

onTaskDragStart(event: any, food: Foods) {
  this.draggedFoodItem = food;
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(food));

}

onTaskDragOver(event: any) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

onTaskDrop(event: any, meal: Meals) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (this.draggedFoodItem) {
    // Add the dragged food item to the meal's food list
    meal.foods.push(this.draggedFoodItem);

    // Remove the dragged food item from the original foods list
    this.foods = this.foods.filter(food => food.id !== this.draggedFoodItem?.id);

    // Clear the dragged item reference
    this.draggedFoodItem = null;
    const totalCalories = meal.foods.reduce((sum, food) => sum + (food.calories || 0), 0);

    meal.calCount = totalCalories;
  }
}

The rest of the code (I have all of the relative components here, with the exception of the one that handles users) handles reloading the data to the page once you've save it, left and come back.
This writes the data to an API, which I didn't include, as this is pretty much just about the drag and drop functions
component.css:
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
  .container input[type=text] {
    width: 150px;
  }
div.settings {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
  div.settings label {
    text-align: right;
  }
    div.settings label:after {
      content: ":";
    }
.food-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
.food-item ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
.food-item ul li{
    padding:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:small;
}
.food-item ul li ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    min-width:70px;
}
  .food-item img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    right:1px;
    z-index:5;
  }
  .food-item div{
      padding: 10px;
  }
.meal-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  min-height:30px;
}
  .meal-item div {
    border: 1px green solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
.makeMeal{
}
.makeMeal img{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
.meal-drop{
    border:1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    min-height:25px;
}
.meal-drop img{
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
}
.meal-drop div{
    clear:both;
    width:fit-content;
    height:auto;
}
.meal-drop button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 6px;
    width: fit-content;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
.target{
    border: 1px blue solid;
    min-width:90%;
    min-height:25px;
}
.plainList{
    list-style:none;
}
  .plainList ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 5px;
    padding:10px;
  }
.plainList li{
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
  .plainList li img{
      height:20px;
      width:20px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1px;
      right:1px;
      cursor:pointer;
  }
.hideFood{
    display:none;
}
.showFood{
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}

component.html:
<div class="container">
  <h2>Build A Meal:</h2>
  <p>My meals:</p>

  <div cdkDropListGroup>
    <div class="makeMeal">

      <ul class="plainList">
        @for(meal of meals; track meal.id; let i = $index){
        <li class="meal-item">
          {{meal.name}}<img src="page_delete.png" (click)="deleteMeal(meal.id, i)" />
          <div class="meal-drop" [attr.draggable]="true"
               (dragover)="onTaskDragOver($event)"
               (drop)="onTaskDrop($event, meal)">

            @for(droppedFood of meal.foods; track droppedFood.id; let j = $index){
            <div>{{ droppedFood.name }}<img src="page_delete.png" (click)="deleteMealFood(meal.id, i, j)" /></div>
            }
            <button (click)="mealSave(meal)">Save</button>
          </div>
          Total calores: {{meal.calCount}}
        </li>
        }
        @empty{
        <li>No meals found</li>
        }
      </ul>

      Add a meal:
      <input id="mealName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="mealName" name="mealName" required style="margin-left:10px;" />
      <img src="page_white_add.png" (click)="addMeal()" />
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <p>My foods:</p>
  <div class="food-grid">
    <ul class="plainList">
      @for(food of foods; track food.id; let i = $index){
      <li class="food-item" [attr.draggable]="true"
          (dragstart)="onTaskDragStart($event, food)">
        <div (click)="toggleActive(food)">
          <img src="page_delete.png" (click)="deleteFood(food.id, i)"  />
          {{food.name}}
        <div [ngClass]="food.isActive? 'showFood' : 'hideFood'">
          calories: {{food.calories}}<br />
          protein: {{food.protein}}<br />
          carbs: {{food.carbs}}<br />
          potassium: {{food.potassium}}
        </div>
        </div>
        
      </li>
      }
      @empty{
      <li>No food items found</li>
      }
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { SaveMealService, Foods, Meals } from '../services/save-meal.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-build-meal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './build-meal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './build-meal.component.css'
})

export class BuildMealComponent {
  private isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  private userId: string = '';
  private bmr: number = 0;
  public message: string = '';
  public calCount: number = 0;
  public foods: Foods[] = [];
  public meals: Meals[] = [];
  public mealName: string = '';
  private draggedFoodItem: Foods | null = null;
  public isActive = false;
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private foodService: SaveMealService,
    private router: Router,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
      var logUser = this.authService.getUserInfo();
      this.userId = this.authService.userID;
      this.bmr = this.authService.bmr;
      this.getFood();
      this.getMeals();      
    }
  }

  addMeal() {
    if (this.mealName.trim()) {
      this.foodService.createMeal(this.userId, this.mealName).subscribe({
        next: (response: number) => {
          this.message = 'Meal created successfully';
          this.getMeals(); // Refresh meal list after adding
          this.mealName = ''; // Clear the input field
        },
        error: (err: number) => {
          this.message = 'Error creating meal: ' + err;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  deleteFood(id: string, index: number) {
    this.foodService.removeFood(this.userId, id).subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.foods.splice(index, 1);
      }
  });
}

  deleteMeal(id: string, meal_index: number) {
    this.foodService.removeMeal(this.userId, id);
    this.meals.splice(meal_index, 1);
  }

  deleteMealFood(meal_id: string, meal_index: number, food_index: number) {
    const id = parseInt(meal_id);
    const foodId = this.meals[id].foods[food_index];
    this.foodService.RemoveMealFood(meal_id, foodId.toString());
  }
  
  getFood() {
    this.foodService.getAllFood(this.userId).subscribe({
      next: (response: Foods[]) => {

        this.foods = response;
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        this.message = 'Error retrieving food: ' + err;
      }
    });
  }

  getMeals() {
    this.foodService.getAllMeals(this.userId).subscribe({
      next: (response: Meals[]) => {
        // Initialize foods array if not already present
        this.meals = response.map(meal => ({
          ...meal,
          foods: meal.foods || [] // Initialize as an empty array if undefined
        }));
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        this.message = 'Error retrieving meals: ' + err;
      }
    });
  }

  mealSave(meal: Meals) {
    this.foodService.saveMeal(meal, meal.id).subscribe(results => {
      console.log('All requests completed:', results);
    });
  }

  onTaskDragStart(event: any, food: Foods) {
    this.draggedFoodItem = food;
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(food));

  }

  onTaskDragOver(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  onTaskDrop(event: any, meal: Meals) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.draggedFoodItem) {
      // Add the dragged food item to the meal's food list
      meal.foods.push(this.draggedFoodItem);

      // Remove the dragged food item from the original foods list
      this.foods = this.foods.filter(food => food.id !== this.draggedFoodItem?.id);

      // Clear the dragged item reference
      this.draggedFoodItem = null;
      const totalCalories = meal.foods.reduce((sum, food) => sum + (food.calories || 0), 0);

      meal.calCount = totalCalories;
    }
  }

  toggleActive(food: any) {
    food.isActive = !food.isActive;
  }

  trackById(index: number, item: any): number {
    return item.id;
  }
}

save-meal.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { forkJoin, Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
export interface Foods {
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  protein: number
  carbs: number,
  potassium: number,
  id: string,
  isActive: boolean
}
export interface Meals {
  name: string,
  id: string,
  calCount: number,
  foods: Foods[]
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SaveMealService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://127.0.0.1:7010/api/Food';
  private apiMealUrl = 'https://localhost:7010/api/Meal';
  private apiTemplateUrl = 'https://127.0.0.1:7010/api/MealTemplate'
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  createMeal(
    userId: string,
    mealName: string

  ): Observable<number> {
    const meal = { userId, mealName };
    
    return this.http.post<number>(`${this.apiMealUrl}/CreateMeal`, meal).pipe(
      tap(response => {
      })
    );
    
  }

  removeFood(userid: string, id: string
  ): Observable<any> {
    const food = { id };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/removeFood?id=${id}`,  {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response'  // Observe the full HTTP response
    }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {  // Check for 'OK' status
          // Perform navigation to login page here (optional)
          console.log(response);
          return response.body as number;  // Return true if the response status is 200 OK
        }
        return -2;
      }),
      catchError(() => of(-3))  // Handle error and return false
    );
  }

  removeMeal(userId: string, id: string) {
    const item = { userId, id };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiMealUrl}/removeMeal`, item, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response'  // Observe the full HTTP response
    }).pipe(
      tap(response => {
      })
    );
  }

  saveMeal(meal: Meals, mealId: string) {
  const foods: Foods[] = meal.foods;

  const requests = foods.map(item => {
    const foodId = item.id.toString(); // Ensure foodId is a string
    
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiTemplateUrl}/SaveMealAsync?foodId=${foodId}&mealId=${mealId}`, { // Wrap menuItem in an "item" property
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(
      map(response => response.status === 200),
      catchError(err => {
        this.errorHandler(err);
        return [false];  // Return false if an error occurs
      })
    );
  });

  return forkJoin(requests); // Return an observable that completes when all requests are done
}

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return throwError(error.message || "server error.");
  }

  getAllFood(userID: string): Observable<Foods[]> {

    return this.http.get<Foods[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/getFoods?id=${userID}`).pipe(
      tap(response => {
      })
    );
  }

  getAllMeals(userId: string): Observable<Meals[]> {
    return this.http.get<Meals[]>(`${this.apiMealUrl}/getMeals?userID=${userId}`).pipe(
      switchMap((meals: Meals[]) => {
        // For each meal, get the associated foods
        const mealsWithFoods$ = meals.map(meal =>
          this.http.get<Foods[]>(`https://127.0.0.1:7010/api/MealTemplate/getFoodsByMeal?mealId=${meal.id}`)
            .pipe(
              map(foods => {
                // Calculate the total calorie count for the meal
                const totalCalories = foods.reduce((acc, food) => acc + food.calories, 0);
                return { ...meal, foods, calCount: totalCalories }; // Include calCount in the meal object
              })
            )
        );

        // Combine all observables into one
        return forkJoin(mealsWithFoods$);
      }),
      tap(response => {
        console.log('Meals with foods and calorie counts:', response);
      })
    );
  }

  RemoveMealFood(
    meal_id: string,
    foodId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiTemplateUrl}/RemoveFood?mealId=${meal_id}&foodId=${foodId}`, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response'  // Observe the full HTTP response
    }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {  // Check for 'OK' status
          // Perform navigation to login page here (optional)
          console.log(response);
          return response;
        }
        return false;
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }

  saveFood(
    userid: string,
    foodName: string,
    calories: number,
    carbohydrates: number,
    protein: number,
    potassium: number,
    servingSize: number,
    portion: number
  ): Observable<number> {
    const food = { userid, foodName, calories, protein, carbohydrates, potassium, servingSize, portion };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/SaveFood`, food, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response'  // Observe the full HTTP response
    }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {  // Check for 'OK' status
          // Perform navigation to login page here (optional)
          console.log(response);
          return response.body as number;  // Return true if the response status is 200 OK
        }
        return -2;
      }),
      catchError(() => of(-3))  // Handle error and return false
    );
  }
 
}


A note on this: do NOT try to get the data from an AI - that was my first mistake. I've found the AI's are WAY behind in the technology and the solutions they generated just didn't work. The AI then tries to slap band-aids on the problem. Also, forgive me if you could code it better, I've only been doing Angular for ~ 3 wks
